# php5 and jQuery ajax return array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to figure out how to use jQuery's `.ajax()` to query a MySQL table and return the results as an array. This is what I have so far:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({url: 'procedures?',
    data: {Action: 'GetSuggestList' },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(oData){
        if(oData.errormsg != null)
              alert('failed: ' + oData.errormsg);
        alert(oData.results);
}});
```

PHP code (with the assumption that my `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` are valid):

```
 $pcAction = isset( $_REQUEST['Action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['Action'] : "" ;
 if($pcAction=='GetSuggestList'){
     $tb_name = 'suggestions';
     echo json_encode( DoGetSuggestList($tb_name) ) ;
 }

 function DoGetSuggestList($ptb_name){
     $qry_suggest = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $ptb_name . ' WHERE Active ORDER BY updated DESC');
     $rsl_suggest = mysql_fetch_array($qry_suggest);
     $jSONreturn = array("errormsg" => $jSONerror, "results" => $rsl_suggest);

     return $jSONreturn;
 };
```

I'm not sure what else needs to be in my AJAX success function in order to iterate through each resulting row in the array...

Comment: If you want all of the results, shouldn't you have that mysql_fetch_array call in a while loop? What does the json you're getting back look like now? (you can use console.log(oData) if you have firebug installed)

Comment: I would echo `$pcAction`... the table name `$tb_name` might not be set

Comment: @machinemessiah - I think you are right about having mysql_fetch_array in a loop because console.log(oData) is returning the results of  just 1 record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to have the results from the query dumped into an associate array before you `json_encode()` them.

```
while( ... ) {
    $a_results[] = array( 's_column' => $row['column'] );
}

return json_encode( array('errormsg' => $jSONerror, 'results' => $a_results) );
```